# C# How do I make StreamReader skip a line when it reads a "~"

Tags: c#, combobox, streamreader

I have to make a windows forms project in visual studio with c# for school, but I don't understand c# (or programming in general really). I've been using tutorials but I'm stuck.
I made it so that multiple types of data - name, phone number, etc, are entered into a text file, with each thing being seperated with a "~". My code currently uses StreamReader to put  each line of the text file into a combo box, but I want it to only put data written before the "~" symbol, and when it detects it it should skip to the next line. Sorry if I explained this badly, I don't understand any of the terms I should be using.

My Code:

```
  private void addSkiTimesPupilCB_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        selectedClass = addSkiTimesPupilCB.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }

    private void addSkiTimes_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("pupilDetails.txt");
            string line = sr.ReadLine();

            while (line != null)
                {
                    string[] components = line.Split("~".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    addSkiTimesPupilCB.Items.Add(line);
                    line = sr.ReadLine();
                }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

The text file is formatted like this:

name~age~phone number

If it means anything, I had to enter "using System.IO;" at the top of the program.

Comment: Does it have to use a StreamReader? I ask because there are simpler ways of reading a file..

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be saying that you want only the `name` from `name~age~number` to appear in the combo

I note that you split the line on `~` but you don't use the result of the split:

```
string[] components = line.Split("~".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
addSkiTimesPupilCB.Items.Add(line);
                             ^^^^
```

If instead here you put `components[0]`, then that would see just the name going into the combo